# Eloquent query for addSelect and whereIn for relational datatables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel 8. I have a 2 datatables that are related. One is 'customers' the other is 'jobs'. One customer can have a history of many jobs. I am trying to build a query using eloquent that will contain a customer and all their jobs in one collection. I have tried a few things and

I most commonly run into the error

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row  (SQL: select `customers`.*, (select `type` from `jobs` where `jobs`.`type` in (HVAC, Select)) as `jobType` from `customers`)

Now I pretty sure its doing this because there is more than one job for the customer but I don't know how to make it so that this is not an issue. Its actually what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have tried a few things:

```
$jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
            ->whereBetween('date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])                    
            ->join('customers', 'customers.location_number', '=', 'jobs.location_number')
            ->join('notes', 'notes.location_number', '=', 'jobs.location_number')
            ->where('jobs.type',$type)
            ->take('30')->get();
```

I have also tried (as a very simple test:

```
$jobs = Customer::addSelect(['jobType' => Job::select('type')
                ->whereIn('jobs.type',$type)])
                ->get();
```

but id doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I think this date `['01-01-1970'` should be presented as `['1970-01-01'`

Comment: Also it does not lool like you are creating a subquery in this code, are you sure the error comes from this code

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The idea remains the same. A collection with a sub collection from related data tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$jobs = Job::join('customers', 'customers.location_number', '=', 'jobs.location_number')
            ->join('notes', 'notes.location_number', '=', 'jobs.location_number')
            ->where('jobs.class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
            ->whereBetween('jobs.date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
            ->where('jobs.type',$type)
            ->take('30')
            ->get();
```

In the `join()` query, you must need to specify the column's name with table in  `where()`, `select()` or `groupBy()` Eloquent functions. e.g: `jobs.class`, `jobs.type`.